# Log Parser 2.2 Registry Wildcard Search

Tags: parsing, search, logging, registry, wildcard

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to do a wildcard registry search using Log Parser 2.2. A sample of what I'm trying to do:

```
try
        {
            LogQuery qry = new LogQuery();
            RegistryInputFormat registryFormat = new RegistryInputFormat();

            string query = @"SELECT Path FROM \HKCU\Software WHERE Value='%keyword%'";
            rs = qry.Execute(query, registryFormat);
            for (; !rs.atEnd(); rs.moveNext())
                listBox1.Items.Add(rs.getRecord().toNativeString(","));
        }
        finally
        {
            rs.close();
        }
```

WHERE Value='%keyword%' does not seem to work and is specific to what is entered in within the '' and specifically searches %keyword% versus the percent signs being wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

Okay nevermind, got it figured out:

```
RegRecordSet rs = null;
        try
        {
            LogQuery qry = new LogQuery();
            RegistryInputFormat registryFormat = new RegistryInputFormat();

            string query = @"SELECT Path FROM \HKCU\Software WHERE Value LIKE '%keyword%'";
            rs = qry.Execute(query, registryFormat);
            for (; !rs.atEnd(); rs.moveNext())
                listBox1.Items.Add(rs.getRecord().toNativeString(","));
        }
        finally
        {
            rs.close();
        }
```